# Type casting with a generic integer

Tags: generics, rust, integer

I have been working on a function which I would like to make generic over all integer types. I have therefore used the `Integer` trait from the `num` crate https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.Integer.html however, my function requires my to be able to type cast both to and from my input type e.g.

```rust
fn main() {
    test(54_u8);
}

fn test<T> (x: T)
where T: num::Integer + std::fmt::Display {
    assert_eq!(10_u64, x as u64);
    assert_eq!(54_i32 as T, x);
}
```

Where the code fails with the error message

```
an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

How can I typecast a generic integer? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`num::FromPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.FromPrimitive.html) and [`num::ToPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.ToPrimitive.html) can help to switch back and forth between `num::Integer` and a concrete type.

```rust
fn main() {
    test(10_u8);
    test(54_u8);
}

fn test<T>(x: T)
where
    T: num::Integer + num::FromPrimitive + num::ToPrimitive + Copy,
{
    if T::from_u64(10) == Some(x) {
        println!("this is ten");
    }
    if let Some(54) = x.to_i32() {
        println!("this is fifty-four");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same crate contains [`num::FromPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.FromPrimitive.html) and [`num::ToPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.ToPrimitive.html) traits. You could use them as

```
fn test<T> (x: T)
where T: num::FromPrimitive + num::ToPrimitive + std::fmt::Debug + Eq + Copy {
    assert_eq!(10_u64, x.to_u64());
    assert_eq!(T::from_i32(54), x);
}
```

Or you could use the standard library's [`Into`/`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html) (or [`TryInto`/`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/try_from_try_into.html) if you want the conversion to be allowed to fail):

```
fn test<T> (x: T)
where T: From<i32> + Into<u64> + std::fmt::Debug + Eq + Copy {
    assert_eq!(10_u64, x.into());
    assert_eq!(T::from(54_i32), x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As a note to anyone viewing this example the first block of code shown above will not work as `to` and `from` calls return an option not a value, so you need to deal with the `option` returned. This option can give you an `Err` in the case you have something like `T` is of type `u8` and you try `T::from_i32(1000)` so it's worth dealing with the `Err` variant.